# Excluding Dependency with Maven Assembly Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have an assembly project with two direct dependencies, a war and an jar. In the assembly descriptor, I am trying to place the war in one folder and the jar in another. As such, I am using the following dependencySet snippet:

```
 <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*:war</include>
        </includes>
        <directoryMode>750</directoryMode>
        <fileMode>660</fileMode>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>mygroup:my-jar-artifact</include> 
        </includes>
        <directoryMode>750</directoryMode>
        <fileMode>660</fileMode>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

However, when I execute "mvn assembly:single", it always ends up placing the jar in the webapps directory. I have tried every possible way to force it to exclude the jar (including adding excludes tags, etc). I know I could do a workaround by using the  by using the maven dependency plugin to copy the jar to a folder and then use the assembly descriptor to copy the flat file over. However, I really feel like I ought to be able to use dependency sets to do this. Any ideas?

Additional information:

- I am using maven 3.0.2 but maven 3.0.3 exhibits the same behavior.
- My pom dependency for the jar uses a 'jar-with-dependencies' classifier.

Comment: For anyone who lands here (misled by the title) trying to figure out why their POM-level dependency exclusions are not being honored by the assembly plugin, [go right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461192/how-to-have-maven-assembly-plugin-respect-the-exclusions-defined-in-pom-xml#49799612).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was going to look at the source code for the assembly plugin to figure out the problem. In doing so, I noticed that I was using assembly 2.2-beta-1. Upgrading to 2.2 fixed the issue entirely. Lesson learned that I should always check the version of the plugin next time.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that it is copying transitive dependencies of the WAR?

Try using either

```
<useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
```

or

```
<useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
```

in the dependencySet of the WAR.

[Assembly Descriptor documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html)

If `useTransitiveDependencies` is turned off (it is on by default), the transitive dependencies of the WAR should not be copied.

If `useTransitiveFiltering` is turned on (it is off by default), the filters you define will apply to the transitive dependencies of the WAR, and since this is including `*:war` should not include any of the dependency JARs when copying.

Comment: I thought about the useTransitiveDependencies tag. However, when I try to use it inside of my DependencySet element, I get the following: " Unrecognised tag: 'useTransitiveDependencies'". It is as if I used an unrecognized tag (I am using maven 3.0.2 but maven 3.0.3 does the same thing). Nonetheless, I used dependency:tree on the war and could see that the jar is not a dependency. Furthermore, when I remove the jar dependency from the assembly project's pom, the problem goes away. Also - the useTransitiveFiltering seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the syntax `*:war` is incorrect.

Can you try specifying the groupId:artifactId explicitly in the `<include>`, the same way that you have done for the `jar` artifact?

```
<includes>
    <include>mygroup:my-war-artifact</include> 
</includes>
```

Comment: I've tried this, too. It still includes the jar artifact. The debug output looks like it is going to do the right thing: "[DEBUG] Statistics for Includes filter:
o 'mygroup:mywarartifact'

[DEBUG] The following artifacts were removed by this artifact inclusion filter: 
mygroup:myjar:jar:myclassifier:myversion"