# How to have maven-assembly-plugin respect the exclusions defined in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

## TL;DR

When some (specific) transitive dependencies are **excluded in the POM file** but the **assembly descriptor is set to fetch all dependencies**, the **excluded dependencies will be included** in assembly. **How can I prevent this?**

## A bit of background

Some dependencies may be tricky to handle because their groupIds and artifactIds change at almost each version (in my case, bouncycastle).

I am retrieving several versions of bouncycastle (138, 1.38, 1.45 and 1.50). My purpose is to eliminate all versions other than 1.50. To be precise, I have one dependency (let's call it `some.perfectly.done:job`) which imports 1.50 and one other (`how.many.castles:do-you-need`) which imports all others. They are corporate dependencies, so giving you real groupId:artifactId wouldn't help you for testing.

#### pom.xml

My dependencies are declared as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.perfectly.done</groupId>
    <artifactId>job</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>how.many.castles</groupId>
    <artifactId>do-you-need</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

#### assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <!-- Adds dependencies to zip package under lib directory -->
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.groupId}.${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <!-- ... -->
</assembly>
```

#### What I get

```
$ ls *bouncycastle*
bouncycastle.bcmail-jdk14-138.jar       org.bouncycastle.bcmail-jdk15on-1.50.jar  org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar
bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk14-138.jar       org.bouncycastle.bcpkix-jdk15on-1.50.jar  org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar
org.bouncycastle.bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar  org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar    org.bouncycastle.bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
```

#### What I expect (and need)

```
$ ls *bouncycastle*
org.bouncycastle.bcmail-jdk15on-1.50.jar  org.bouncycastle.bcpkix-jdk15on-1.50.jar  org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar
```

## Some possible leads to build upon

The real value in an answer here would be to find a *real*, *generic* solution. I am not looking to solve *my* case, I'd like to find a solution for all people with a similar case.

As such, I'd like to avoid some solutions which would work but are really related to a particular case and often requires to duplicate the POM's logic into the assembly descriptor.

These are however leads that may help if nothing better can be found.

#### Reproduce the exclusion pattern inside the assembly descriptor

Obviously. In my own case though, quite impractical, except by the intelligent use of `includes`/`excludes`. This is not a practical solution.

#### Make several dependency sets

Note that I am aware [this question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29139119/1734119), but the only attempt at an answer is unsatisfactory for my case:

> If you have such thing you need to define two dependencySet entries one which include the logback [with `useTransitiveDependencies=false`] and other.

<sub>(by [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise))</sub>

#### Use `maven-dependency-plugin`

On [the same question as above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29139119/1734119), an approach which I might use if no question is asked has been proposed: first use [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to copy my correct dependencies to a temporary directory, then assemble my zip from this directory.

As a workaround, this is probably the most valid solution, as being generic and not duplicating the logic from the POM in the assembly descriptor, though this makes the build longer.

## Side question: Why?

Why does the `maven-assembly-plugin` behave this way? I did not find any reference to this in the documentation. Is it desired behavior, or is it a (known/unknown) bug?

Comment: I've just seen your post, I'm having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272126/maven-dependency-exclusions-in-pom-xml-are-not-excluded-by-assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit

Version `3.1.1` of the `maven-assembly-plugin` [have been released Jan 01, 2019](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/3.1.1). It solves the JIRA issues mentioned in my answer below (kept for history or for users that cannot upgrade the plugin). With this version, `maven-assembly-plugin` **now honors wildcards in dependencies exclusions**. Simply upgrade the plugin.

#### Answer for `maven-assembly-plugin` version <= 3.1.0

It appears that Maven assembly plugin (**version <= 3.1.0**) does not honor exclusions using wildcards (`*`), see [MASSEMBLY-762](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-762), [MASSEMBLY-861](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MASSEMBLY/issues/MASSEMBLY-861) or [MASSEMBLY-675](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-675). From the last JIRA issue, the problem will be solved in version `3.1.1` of the plugin (see [commit](https://github.com/apache/maven-assembly-plugin/commit/78faddf88b1537bc5c61ba74cdb2b227416152b6)). <s>At the moment of writing, the `3.1.1` version is not released : `3.1.0` is the latest version</s>.

Hopefully, the problem can be solved with version <= 3.1.0.

To do so, just declare the right excluded artifacts instead of `*`, and it works properly. It can be painful to list all excluded dependencies, but at least I think it is a better solution than the accepted one (less tweaking of Maven phases), especially on multi-modules project with cross dependencies (my case). Moreover, by doing so, you have more control about the dependencies.

Hope that helps, waiting the `3.1.1` version! :)

Comment: Hi, nice input. Thanks! I did not accept my own answer as, indeed, I found it dirty. Please do not hesitate to test and update the plugin as soon as it is out. If it's OK, just update the answer and you'll be accepted. :) (notify me in a comment so I'm aware of the update, though)

Comment: @Chop I've just noticed that a newer version of `maven-assembly-plugin` have been released at the beginning of the year (it solves your issue). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

## Use the `maven-dependency-plugin`

Though not the ultimate solution I am looking for, this may help people who are in an emergency.

#### pom.xml

In your POM, define the following property (adapt the path to your preferences):

```
<properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <assembly.lib.directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</assembly.lib.directory>
    <!-- ... -->
</properties>
```

In the `<build/>` section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${assembly.lib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <prependGroupId>true</prependGroupId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### assembly.xml

The idea is replacing the `dependencySet` with a `fileSet`:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <!-- Adds dependencies to zip package under lib directory -->
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${assembly.lib.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>

        <!-- ... -->
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Edit: as [highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093812/1734119) by [user716401](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716401/user716401), it is better to execute the `dependencies:copy-dependencies` in `prepare-package` phase to ensure it runs before `assembly:single`.

Comment: Note - the pre-package phase is actually called "prepare-package"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a spring maven project. Looking at the pom.xml file I had the following two bouncycastle dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.50</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.50</version>
</dependency>
```

I was able to remove `bcprov-jdk15on` dependency block safely as nothing seemed to be dependent on it since a subsequent build was successful, however, the issue was still present. So I ran the following maven command after updating the dependency plugin version to 2.10 in the pom.xml file from 2.6 that did not work.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=bouncycastle
```

This gave the output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dhtexasAdmin 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ dhtexasAdmin ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, 
[INFO] com.dhtexasadmin:dhtexasAdmin:war:1.0
[INFO] \- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:jar:R8pre2:compile
[INFO]    \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]       +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:136:compile
[INFO]       \- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:136:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.324 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-21T16:58:52+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/39M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I had to add an exclusion for the bcprov-jdk14 in the xhtmlrenderer section as below, following the example [Maven Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
    <version>R8pre2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After which a `mvn clean` followed by `mvn package` did the trick.

Comment: Hi! This is a great answer (and well written, as far as I'm concerned) on what transitive dependencies are and how to determine what to exclude. It does not however answer my question: I _have_ excluded dependencies, but the `maven-assembly-plugin` still included them into the package it built. I had to workaround with the `maven-dependency-plugin`.